# Classification of degree 3 rational maps on a hyperelliptic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

It's amazing how far in life you can get with theorems, without stopping to do any calculations.

Let $\Sigma_2$ be a genus $2$ curve embedded in the projective plane given by the equation $z^4 y^2 = \prod_{i=1}^6 (x - z \zeta_i)$ in homogenous coordinates, with the $\zeta_i$ of course being the fixed points of the hyperelliptic involution. I want to understand what the possible degree $3$ rational maps are from $\Sigma_2$ to $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Since the maps I'm interested in are rational maps, we just work in affine coordinates. This is convenient because as written, such a curve is singular at $[0:1:0]$ in the projective plane, and I don't want to have to compute the normalization. Now this reduces the problem to fidning when $[\mathbb{C}(x,y):f^\ast(\mathbb{C}(t))] = 3$ where $t$ is the local coordinate on $\mathbb{C}$, and $x,y$ satisfy $y^2 = \prod(x-\zeta_i)$.

Prima facie this happens in two ways. By finding a degree $1$ map from $\Sigma_2 \to \mathbb{CP}^1$ and composing with a degree $3$ map from the sphere to itself, and by finding a genuine degree $3$ map. The former isn't possible though, since a degree $1$ map would be an isomorphism.

Such a map is of course defined by what it does to $t$. So I send $t \mapsto F(x,y)$. Is there a strategy for computing the degree? Somehow I have made it this far in my life and only seen trivial examples, where the fields in question are things like $\mathbb{Q}(\text{radicals and stuff})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. In an attempt to figure this out, I noticed that I can write this as $F(x,y) = \frac{P(x,y)}{Q(x,y)}$, and then $P,Q$ can be written as polynomials in $y$, i.e. $P(x) = P_1(x) + yP_2(x)$ using the equation of the curve.

Now the degree of $F$ is the difference of the degrees of $P$ and $Q$, so I just need to compute these degrees. I believe that the degree of $y$ is $6$ (after being enlightened in the comments) since a generic choice of $y$, we will obtain a polynomial of degree $6$, having $6$ solutions. and the degree of $P_1, Q_1$ should be simply their degrees as polynomials in $x$.

Is all this correct? If so, then I think this tells us roughly how to classify the maps on hyperelliptic curves of a given degree.

Comment: Just some comments: 1) Typically one embeds a genus $2$ curve in weighted projective space $\mathbb{P}(1,3,1)$ to avoid having singularities at infinity. Then the curve is simply given by $y^2 = \prod_{i=1}^6 (x - z \zeta_i)$. 2) Now that we have that $\Sigma_2$ is a smooth curve, every rational map to $\mathbb{P}^1$ is a morphism. 3) $x$ is a degree $2$ map: for a fixed $x_0$ there are two possible $y$-values. Correspondingly, $y$ has degree $6$.

Comment: I have never even heard of a weighted projective space. I guess I'll take a look at this and see if it helps straighten me out. Or if anyone wants to elaborate in an answer in the near future.

Comment: I'll write a more complete post later, but here's the idea of how to get functions of degree $3$. There are two points at infinity, $\infty_+ = (1:1:0)$ and $\infty_- = (1:-1:0)$; $x$ has a simple pole at both of them and $y$ has a pole of order $3$ at both of them. We can start with $y$ and add a degree $3$ polynomial in $x$ to cancel out the pole at $\infty_-$. For instance, if $\Sigma: y^2 = x^6 - 1$, then $y+x^3$ has degree $3$ and $\operatorname{div}(y+x^3) = 3\infty_- - 3\infty_+$.

Comment: I had this thought in the last hour or so. I'm not ready to answer my own question yet since I don't feel I've understood everything, but I will keep thinking. Worst case, I'll answer my own question as well, and then accept your answer.